# Audio problems after resuming from suspend/sleep

Tags: sound

My audio become broken or garbled after waking up from suspend. I find I need to do a restart to get my audio to work.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Please provide more details about your situation, so other people can help you. Information like the Ubuntu version and your hardware would be a good starting point.